# Replacing text on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to take input of text by user which will replace a written text on webpage. just think i have a name in  html, i have made form in which type his name and press (okay) after this, the name in  tag replace by the name input by user and I have styled text by CSS written in  tag.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Yo gonna be downvoted if you don't post any code or just the code you tried. Please let us see what you do.

Comment: Grab the value of the input. Select the html element that needs to be updated. Change it's value/innerHTML/innerText to the name.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to hire a web developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//make sure the DOM is finished loading then execute our script
//by putting it in a ready function

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ok').click(function(e) {
    $('#result').addClass('sent'); // add styles to the submitted content
    var nameVal = $('#nameField').val(); // get value in form field

    //set the value of your div to form value
    $('#result').addClass('sent').html(nameVal);
  })

})
```

```css
.sent {
// add custom styles here
   color:red;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameField" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  <input class="ok" type="button" value="Ok">
</form>




<div id="result">Value will be here</div>
```